# Unable to list laravel routes because target class not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working on an API only laravel application. In the controllers folder, there is an API folder that holds all controllers. The `ForgotPasswordController` is in the API folder as well.

When I run the command `php artisan route:list` I get the error below

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController] does not exist.

There is actually no ForgotPasswordController in the `Auth` folder. How do I handle this issue?

Comment: @RolandStarke nice but that didn't help me fix the issue of listing out the route

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I have `API\ForgotPasswordController` and it works fine. The reason I wanted to list out the routes is because after adding a new route in `api.php` file and running `php artisan route:cache` the route keeps returning `resource not found`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you are doing `php artisan route:cache` priority.

If the problem still persists, can you disable the auth provider and try?

Comment: Yes I ran `php artisan route:cache` a couple of times and still not able to list out all the routes because of the error mentioned

Comment: I had such a problem and it was related to the auth provider sorry the problem was not solved :(

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of time considering that the project is live and I need to churn out a couple of features, I have moved both ForgotPassword and ResetPassword controllers back into the `Auth` folder. Ran a test to make sure nothing has been broken (everything works fine) and now I am able to list out the routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Auth::routes()` or `Route::auth()` in your routes file that would be generating routes to the `ForgotPasswordController`.

You would need to not be calling that or you would need to pass the proper option to it to have it not register those routes:

```
Auth::routes(['reset' => false]);
```

Depending on the version you are using this may not work. If that is the case you will have to not use this method at all and register the routes you want/need yourself.